# F11 key does not work as function key in MacBook Pro 14"

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, mac, settings

I have a MacBook Pro 14" M2 Pro Chip. I have noticed that the `F11` key has volume low and when I press it without the `fn` key, it works normally (it lowers the volume as expected). However, when I press it with `fn`, it does nothing. (all other function keys work normally) I went to settings to use the function keys as standard function keys. Still, nothing happens on pressing `F11`, however now if I press `fn + F11`, it lowers the volume as expected. Why is the F11 key not working? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect F11 to do, when it's not being used as a Special Function key?

Comment: @Tetsujin I use the F11 key in an app. Also, it is not just the app, I checked with some online keyboard key tests.

Comment: Do you have it assigned to a command in Keyboard prefs?

Comment: @Tetsujin Not unless it is by default

Comment: Check with [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware)

Comment: I've had my keys custom-set for so long I don't recall if it was ever assigned as a default.